# text and input elements appended and given attributes the same way. Text shows but not the input. Why?

Tags: javascript, input, d3.js

I have these snippets of code. The `text` element is displayed, but not the `input`. Why?

```
g.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {return d.label; });

g.append("input")
    .attr("type", "text");

svg.selectAll("text")
    .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x+15; })
    .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.y+5; });

svg.selectAll("input")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x + 30; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 20; });
```

PS: also tried `append("xhtml:input")` and `dx`+`dy` instead of `x`+`y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) element is not a valid SVG element, and it doesn't have attributes `x` and `y`.